# Hibernate + MySQL + rewriteBatchedStatements=true

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jdbc

I'm having the following Hibernate configuration:

```
<prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3336/db</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">20</prop>
```

and the following mapping file:

```
<hibernate-mapping default-lazy="false">
    <class name="Table" table="TABLE" batch-size="10" dynamic-update="true">
        <id name="id" column="ID">
            <generator class="uuid"/>
        </id>
        <property name="name" column="NAME" not-null="true"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

If execute this, it's working fine:

```
sessionFactory.getSession().beginTransaction();
    sessionFactory.getSession().save(new Table());
    sessionFactory.getSession().save(new Table());
    sessionFactory.getSession().save(new Table());
    sessionFactory.getSession().save(new Table());
sessionFactory.getSession().getTransaction().commit();
```

However, adding `rewriteBatchedStatements=true` to `hibernate.connection.url`:

```
<prop key="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3336/db?rewriteBatchedStatements=true</prop>
```

Throws the following exception on commit:

```
org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchedTooManyRowsAffectedException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 4; expected: 1
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.checkBatched(Expectations.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.verifyOutcome(Expectations.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.checkRowCounts(BatchingBatcher.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:133)
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I was using MySQL Connector/J 5.1.28 which had this bug:
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68562. Downgrading to 5.1.24 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I also met this issue, and fixed it by updating mysql connector to 5.1.36:

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.36</version>
    </dependency>
```